# Factoring $1 + 2\cos(\theta_1) x + 4i\sin(\theta_1) \cos(\theta_2) x^2 + x^3=0$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Is it possible to factorize the cubic
$$1 + 2\cos(\theta_1) x + 4i\sin(\theta_1) \cos(\theta_2) x^2 + x^3=0$$
without explicitly using the cubic equation? Given the coefficients, the equation will expand to
$$1 + (e^{i\theta_1} + e^{-i\theta_1}) x + (e^{i\theta_1} - e^{-i\theta_1})(e^{i \theta_2} + e^{i \theta_2}) x^2 + x^3=0$$
but I am unsure of how best to proceed.

**Note 1:** I can already factor the analogous quadratic equation

$$
\begin{align}
& 1 + 2x \cos(\theta) + x^2 = \\
& 1 + (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i \theta}) x + x^2 = \\
& (1 + e^{i \theta}x) (1 + e^{-i\theta}x) = \\
& (e^{i\theta} + x) (e^{-i \theta} + x) = 0
\end{align}
$$

**Note 2:** I had also entertained using a Tschirhausen transformation with the hope of simplifying the form of the equation.

Comment: what are you trying to prove to yourself? or better still why not use the cubic equation?

Comment: I was curious if a more elegant alternative to the cubic formula existed for polynomials whose coefficients could be expanded in terms of $e^{i \theta}$. For the order $2$ polynomial, I was able to express it in a manner dictated by Vieta's formulas, and I had hoped that a simple generalization existed for cubic equations.